# stuck copying files from folder to folder or usb drive

Tags: release-juno, usb-drive

the process bar from copy files gets stuck even when its done or it gets stuck mid-way through a process. Is there a way to fix this?

Also, I tried using Ctrl Alt F1 to try to close this process but i actually don't know how to effectly ue Ctrl Alt F1. Can someone please comment on this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to copy files using terminal? If not, give it a try and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Felinux - welcome to the Elementary OS forums!

Let's start off with a few basics to try to diagnose your problem.

1. Please go to Applications -> Terminal (or Win+T)
2. Insert a flash disk into any available USB port.
3. Type: `lsblk`
4. In my case, I can "see" the drive at [/dev/]sda1 and the mount point is at /media/*userID*/*driveName*
**NOTE:** where *userID* is replaced with your eOS username.
Also, *driveName* is replaced with the name of the flash drive.
5. **GIVEN:** I have a bookmarks.json backup file in my Documents folder.
6. Type: `cp ~/Documents/bookmarks.json /media/userID/driveName/`
**NOTE:** You will have to replace bookmarks.json with a file in **your** Documents folder.  Remember to replace *userID* and *driveName* as you did with step #4.
7. If the file copied without errors (which would appear in Terminal) then you can issue the following command.
Type: `ls -al /media/userID/driveName/`
8. You should see a listing of **all** of the files, including the file you just copied, on your flash drive.
9. Press Cont+D to exit the terminal.

If this process works, then we can examine which file(s) you are attempting to copy and why Elementary OS GUI is experiencing difficulties in trying to copy your files to your destination.

Good luck!